# Open source runtime form designer

Tags: cross-platform, wysiwyg, form-designer, scada

I'm searching for an open source runtime form designer (for SCADA, not searching for html designer), which is somewhat similar to modern IDE WYSIWYG's. So far, my list is empty.

Requirements are crossplatform and C++.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Currently I'm using wxWidgets as the GUI platform. So the possible solutions are either open-source wxWidgets based form designer, or the wxWidgets component/lib.

**UPDATE 2:**

Found the [wxShapeFramework](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/shapeframework/) component which is I was looking for. At the moment this is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use wxShapeFramework, which purpose is exactly as described in question (SCADA runtime form designer). Especially because the project is based on wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) would satisfy your needs. It is possible to extend it's functionality with new components. It's not out-of-the-box solution, but may fulfill this role.

Comment: I'm currently using wxWidgets, which is also open-source GUI toolkit. The problem is that I don't want to create runtime form designer from scratch..

Comment: Part of Qt is Qt Designer (I have no idea, how is it licensed), which might be foundation of your application. I'm sure it's a lot of work, to make it work, but still - you wouldn't start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) and [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/)?

Comment: That's an option.. But still, with wxShapeFramework development will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Qt allows you to use UI files created with the designer on-the-fly, without compiling them into your applications. You want the QtUiTools module. See: http://www.forum.nokia.com/infocenter/topic/Qt_for_S60_Developers_Library/GUID-ECBE8350-9D54-48D1-B777-264B895B9063/designer-using-a-ui-file.html and http://www.forum.nokia.com/infocenter/topic/Qt_for_S60_Developers_Library/GUID-ECBE8350-9D54-48D1-B777-264B895B9063/qtuitools.html.